# Continuity of two variable function $f( x,y)$ at $(0,0)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

If function $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{sin((xy)^{2})}{(x^2+y^2)^{\alpha}(xy)^{\alpha}} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 
0& (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$
is continuous at $(0,0)$ , then

$1$. $\alpha <1$.

$2$. $\alpha >1/2$.

$3$. $\alpha <1/3$.

$4$. $\alpha <1/2$.

I tried it as below

$$ lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{sin((xy)^{2})}{(x^2+y^2)^{\alpha}(xy)^{\alpha}} =\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(xy)^{2-\alpha }}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha}$$   Now $r$ power in numerator( after changing into polar form by $x=rcos(\theta), y=rsin(\theta)$) is  $$r^{4-4\alpha}$$ So to exist limit i put $4-4\alpha >0$ and $2-\alpha \geq 0$ and I get $\alpha<1$, but answer is given options $1$, $3$ and $4$th . Please help me to solve it . Thank you .

Comment: So is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$ if $\alpha = 3/4$?

Comment: @aschepler sir I only get condition that $\alpha $ can’t bigger than $1$.

Comment: Try it the other way around - plug in the exact value $3/4$ and see if you can show if that particular function $f$ converges. Not helpful for finding the exact set of $\alpha$, but helpful for checking and understanding an answer, and often a quick way to narrow down multiple choice.